# When will my site be able to use the new "Discover" report in Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

In some one search console account we see the **Discover** option to left side but in my search console account it's not display. My account is new. How much it will take a time to display a discover option. My website article is also optimized for discover.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Google said this report is available in the new Google Search Console for “websites that have accumulated meaningful visibility in Discover.” The data is going back to March 2019 and will continue to grow from there.